# How to find the query sent through ODAC to Oracle Database when using Entity Framework (EF)

Tags: .net, oracle, entity-framework, odac

I am using Oracle ODAC for EntityFramework. I am trying to develop a sample silverlight application using entityframework. I have add my domainservice through which I am publishing my entities. I am UI's code behind file. I have written the following code.

```
var threemonthsold = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3);
var query = serverContext.GetSR_MERGED_DATAQuery().Where(t => t.SR_DATE_RECD > threemonthsold);

var regionLoadOp = serverContext.Load(query);
dataGrid.ItemsSource = regionLoadOp.Entities;
```

I want to find out what query has been sent to oracle. As the operation is getting timedout the application is crashing. Looks like the query is taking long time. If I can find out the query I can run it directly on oracle and find out how long it is taking there.

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer for this question in the [following forum.](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2312460):

```
cshay Dec 3, 2011 9:58 AM (in response to 900653)
You can turn on ODP.NET tracing. See the ODP.NET doc for more details:

1) Close VS
2) In windows registry, change registry value 
    \\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\ODP.NET\4..........\TraceLevel
    to 1
3) Relaunch VS
4) Reproduce the problem
5) Close VS2010
6) Look for the odpnet trace file in the root of C I believe.
7) Undo the registry value (set it back to 0) so you don't impact performance
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're sending queries across the network, [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org) is a great way to view the actual packets being transferred. If you type `TNS` in for the packet filter (not the capture filter, but the one that's on the main page and turns red/green on invalid/valid input), you can see Oracle packets.

[image: Screenshot of oracle packet in wireshark found using <code>tns</code> filter and Find Packet searching for the string 'select' in the packet's bytes.]

It seems that there is [no maintained packet dissector](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Oracle) to show the different parts of the packet, but you can look at the data bytes and see ASCII text showing the SQL statements. (You'll also see a bunch of session open/close junk.)